# Image Right placement

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I need the Stars logo to align top right, but I can only align right and it seems to begin below the text on the left.

I also the border is not visible on the text box.

```css
.text-box {
    background-color: #e9ebe9;
    width:90%;
    padding:20px;
    margin:12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 2px #bfc6bf;
}
```

```html
 <div class="text-box">
        <p>STARS Air Ambulance<br>
        Nutrien Hangar<br>
        2475 Airport Rd<br>
        Saskatoon, SK<br>
        S7L 1M4</p>
            <img src="../images/stars-ally2.jpg" align="right" width="104" height="180" alt=""/>
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><a href="https://stars.ca/" target="_blank" class="button icon solid fa-file">Click To Donate!</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
```

[Text box with image below text instead of right aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0C3r.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use display flex and justify-content. You can read about it here: [Display-flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)
You also need to set border type (solid, dotted...).

```css
.text-box {
    background-color: #e9ebe9;
    width:90%;
    padding:20px;
    margin:12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #bfc6bf;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
<div>
        <p>STARS Air Ambulance<br>
        Nutrien Hangar<br>
        2475 Airport Rd<br>
        Saskatoon, SK<br>
        S7L 1M4</p>
        <ul class="actions">
                    <li><a href="https://stars.ca/" target="_blank" class="button icon solid fa-file">Click To Donate!</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../images/stars-ally2.jpg" align="right" width="104" height="180" alt=""/>
            </div>
    </div>
```